# Counting a set of characters in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to count a set of characters, 'qed' in a string. My idea is to iterate through each character in a given string and if N(i), N(i-1), N(i-2) matches 'qed', update the count but failed so far. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
def test(N):
    s = ('qed')
    count = 0
        for i in range(len(N)):
            if N[i] + N[i-1] + N[i-2] == s:
                count = count + 1
        return print(count)
test('qedmlqedlolqed')
```

Comment: `for i in N:` will loop through the characters in the string...  You want to loop in the range of the length.

Comment: Ok, so first, you have to indent function bodies correctly. 2: You don't have to put a string literal in brackets 3: you meant `for i in range(len(N))`, otherwise it will iterate over the chars not the indices 4: indexing is done by `N[i]` not by `N(i)` 5: `i, i-1, i-3` where is `i-2`? 6: string will be underindexed when `i<3` (does not throw error but will take chars at the end) 7: string concatenation is done by `+` not `&` 8: `return print(count)` makes little sense, try `print(count)` and `return count` in separate lines

Comment: And you can write `count += 1`, but that's not an error (neither is number 2: brackets around a string literal)

Comment: @hege_hegedus Thanks. I've edited the code.

Comment: @hege_hegedus N[i] would not call the characters in N. Instead, it counts the index of the characters.

Comment: 10: indentation is wrong after `if`, 11: you concat the characters in reverse order. `N[i-2] + N[i-1] + N[i]` is the way to go

Comment: *N[i] would not call the characters in N. Instead, it counts the index of the characters.* a character is not callable. `N[i]` does not count anything, it is called indexing, it will retrieve the ith character of N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing your code:

```
def test(N):
    s = 'qed'
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(N)-2):
        if N[i:i+3] == s:
            count += 1
    return count

>>> test('qedmlqedlolqed')
3
```

Or more generally:

```
def test(N, s):
    count = 0
    if s:
        for i in range(len(N)-len(s)+1):
            if N[i:i+len(s)] == s:
                count += 1
    return count

>>> test('qedmlqedlolqed', 'qed')
3
>>> test('qedmlqedlolqed', 'ed')
3
>>> test('qedmlqedlolqed', 'd')
3
>>> test('qedmlqedlolqed', '')
0
>>> test('qedmlqedlolqed', 'lol')
1
>>> test('qedmlqedlolqed', 'rofl')
0
```

---

Or, much easier, using `str.count()`:

```
>>> 'qedmlqedlolqed'.count('qed')
3
```

'

Comment: Would you like to explain why u used `range(len(N)-2)` and `N[i:i+3]`. For `N[i:i+3]`, i'm assuming you're saying taking from index 0 to index 0+3 than compare that == s right?

Comment: @misheekoh: that's right. You take runs of 3 characters starting from the beginning of the string and ending 3 before the end of the string. Compare each of them to the target string. `N[i:i+3]` is a slice that returns the 3 character string starting from index `i`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> 'qedmlqedlolqed'.count('qed')
3
```

Edit: Why the downvote? The question asks *"Any suggestions?"* and I think this is a good one.

Comment: I'm not trying to use the count method here. Thanks though!

Comment: Not trying to use it, or trying to not use it? The former doesn't make sense to say, and the latter should've been mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

though Stefan's answer is simplest and lucid, here's another way to do it using list comprehension

s = 'qedmlqedlolqed'

result = len([1 for i in range(len(s)) if s[i:i+3] == 'qed'])
(thanks Stefan)

Comment: No need to use `s[i:i+3]` for the elements in the throw-away-list, you could just use let's say `1`. Or just use the more straight-forward `sum(s[i:i+3] == 'qed' for i in range(len(s)))`.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing your code:

```
def test(N):
  s = 'qed'
  count = 0
  for i in range(2, len(N)):
    if N[i-2] + N[i-1] + N[i] == s:
      count = count + 1
  return count
print(test('qedmlqedlolqed'))
```

Or you could count how many suffixes of the string starts with qed:

```
def test2(word, sub):
  return sum(1 for i,_ in enumerate(word) if word[i:].startswith(sub))
print(test2('qedmlqedlolqed', 'qed'))
```

Or you could just literally count all the substrings, and check the number of yours:

```
import collections
def all_substrings(s):
  for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(i, len(s)):
      yield s[i:j+1]

def test3(word, sub):
  return collections.Counter(all_substrings(word))[sub]
print(test3('qedmlqedlolqed', 'qed'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `find` repeatedly:

```
>>> text = 'qedmlqedlolqed'
>>> count = index = 0
>>> while True:
        index = text.find('qed', index) + 1
        if not index:
            break
        count += 1

>>> count
3
```

I went with `+ 1` instead of `+ 3` to also support overlapping occurrences (can't happen with `'qed'` or with any other "set of characters", assuming what you meant with that is a string without duplicates).